# VBA code required to loop through different sized rows of data and return MAX value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, max

I am currently automating a dashboard creation and I've hit a bit of a roadblock. I need some code that will go through about 7000 rows of data and return the highest value in a certain column for each specific item. The data is copied from a pivot table and so is broken down into row sections, I have attached a mock of what it looks like.

[image]

I need the highest value in Column G for each portfolio, and will need to use the portfolio code (e.g. XY12345 - They are always 7 characters) to map that value to the dashboard.

My issue is, each portfolio has a different number of rows for the values, and some have blank cells between them, and therefore I am stumped. I was hoping to use Column J to count the number of rows for each portfolio (as there are no breaks for the portfolios in this column) and then use a loop to loop through each portfolios rows of values, based off the Column J count, and then return the highest row value for each portfolio. Problem is I'm new to VBA and have been teaching myself as I go, and I've yet to use a loop.

Many thanks,

Harry

Comment: Can you show us the code you have written so far...

Comment: Note `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max()` and https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Comment: @rohrl77 I haven't written any code yet as I'm not sure where to start as I'm unfamiliar with loops

Comment: I have come up with a solution. Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for the largest value in `Column G`.

I'm not sure why you think you would need VBA for this.

---

## Get the maximum value of a column

You mentioned that you're concerned about each column not having the same number of cells but that's irrelevant. as **`SUM` ignores blank cells**, so just "go long", or - find the maximum of the entire column.

> **To return the largest number in `Column G`** you could use worksheet formula :
>
> `=MAX(G:G)`

The only catch is that you can't place that formula anywhere column G or else it would create a circular cell reference (trying to infinitely add a number to itself).  let's pit that formula in cell `F1` for now (but anywhere besides column `G` would do fine).

---

### Find the location of a value

Now that you know the largest value, you can determine **where** it is using a lookup function such as `MATCH` or `VLOOKUP`.  Like with so many things in Excel, there are several ways to accomplish the same thing.  I'll go with [`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a).

**Replace the formula from above (in `F1`) with:**

> `=MATCH(MAX(G:G),G:G,0)`

This will return the **row number** of the *first* exact match of the maximum value of `Column G`.

---

As for the third part of question: returning the code like `X12345` where the value exists, will be a little tricky since **your data is not organized in a logical *tabular* style** ([tabular](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/tabular) meaning, *"like a table"*).

Your data is organized for *humans* to look at, not for machines to easily read and manipulate it.  (See: Office Support: [**Guidelines for organizing and formatting data on a worksheet**](https://support.office.com/article/guidelines-for-organizing-and-formatting-data-on-a-worksheet-90895cad-6c85-4e02-90d3-8798660166e3))

Basically, when organizing data in rows, all relevant information should be on the same row (not a subjective number of rows behind). Also, you have the number combined with other information.

**My suggestion for a quick fix:**

1. Right-click the heading of `Column C` and choose `Insert` to insert a blank column.
2. In `C2` enter formula: `=IF(B2="",C1,LEFT(B2,7))`
3. Copy cell `C2`
4. Select cells in column C all the way to the "end" of your data, where ever that is (*not* the end of the worksheet). For example maybe you would select cells `B2:B1000`)
5. Paste the copied cell into all those cells.

Now, you can **again modify the formula in `F1`**:

> `=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(MAX(G:G),G:G,0))`

This will return the value from `Column C` in the same row that the maximum value of `Column G` is located.

**This is known as an `INDEX/MATCH` formula.**

Hopefully this works for you in the interim until you can organize your data more logically.  There's lots of related information and tutorials online.

Comment: If there's some reason you indeed need to use VBA for this instead of worksheet functions, you can call the worksheet functions from VBA using [`Application.WorksheetFunction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction).

Comment: Hi Ashleedawg,

Thanks for the quick response.

The reason I need it in VBA is because it's going into my VBA code that automates the pulling of data from drives and then creates a sheet with a Dashboard Data that has been populated with various data sources by using the portfolio codes. As for organising my data more logically, this is out of my control, as this is the format the data is in. If i were to change it, it would be relatively manual unfortunately, and this would defeat the point of the automation.

Comment: I know how to do the process manually in excel, but as I need it automated, I was looking for a way to do it in VBA. And the main sticking point is working with the difficult data layout, hence why I posted on here. Hope that clarifies things.
Thanks

Comment: I also need the largest values in column g for each individual portfolio, not just the whole column.